# No Wi-Fi Adapter found after Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade for Dell XPS 15 L502X

Tags: drivers, wireless, dell, 20.04, iwlwifi

I tried most of the steps and solutions but didn't work.

My wifi is not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

In the wifi option it's showing that 'No Wi-Fi adapter found' Make sure you have a wifi adapter plugged and turned on.

The output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280`:

amit@Amit:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5325]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi, wl
amit@Amit:~$

The output of `dmesg | grep iwl`:

amit@Amit:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[   17.971913] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'auto_agg' ignored
[   17.971914] iwlwifi: unknown parameter 'swctypto' ignored
[   17.971916] iwlwifi: `111n_disable=8bt_coex_active=1power_save=0' invalid for parameter`11n_disable'
amit@Amit:~$

The output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

amit@Amit:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 34
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f1b00000-f1b01fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 06
       serial: 84:8f:69:b6:09:0c
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1804000-f1804fff memory:f1800000-f1803fff
amit@Amit:~$

Other info :

amit@Amit:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:0941 HP, Inc X500 Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:2fb1 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
amit@Amit:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
04:00.0 USB controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 04)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
amit@Amit:~$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
amit@Amit:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    0.148019] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.181070] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
amit@Amit:~$ wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&

> chmod +x wireless-info &&
>     ./wireless-info
>   --2020-06-09 21:58:40--  https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info
>   Resolving github.com (github.com)... 13.234.176.102
>   Connecting to github.com (github.com)|13.234.176.102|:443... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
>   Location: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/master/wireless-info [following]
>   --2020-06-09 21:58:41--  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/master/wireless-info
>   Resolving raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)... 151.101.152.133
>   Connecting to raw.githubusercontent.com (raw.githubusercontent.com)|151.101.152.133|:443... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
>   Length: 17452 (17K) [text/plain]
>   Saving to: ‘wireless-info’

wireless-info       100%[===================>]  17.04K  --.-KB/s    in 0.02s

Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
2020-06-09 21:58:41 (708 KB/s) - ‘wireless-info’ saved [17452/17452]

Results saved in "/home/amit/wireless-info.txt".

The wifi network is not listing and I'm not able to find the solution. Can someone help me and connect with me ?

Comment: "iwlwifi: unknown parameter" Very troubling. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` Also, you went to the trouble to create the wireless_info report but haven't yet posted it for us to analyze: "Results saved in "/home/amit/wireless-info.txt"." Please paste the rsult here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This issue has been fixed later with a software upgrade which basically upgraded the kernel and installed missing drivers. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Trozan_aks1 Can you provide more details on the fix?  What kernel version did you upgrade to?  I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1 with kernel 5.8.0-41 and wifi is not functioning.  Any more details you can provide would be super helpful.